# static analysis tool for android apk

Tags: java, android, testing, static-analysis

Are you guys familiar with any tool that does the job of static analysis of an android apk? I want to have the total method count in a third party apk.

Comment: That doesn't sound like static analysis so much as disassembly and grepping...

Comment: its a part of static analysis, as I want to determine functional coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this tool [Scandroid](http://github.com/scandroid/scandroid)

you need to slightly modify the DexIClass.java class to have the list of all the methods.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links :

[Android Assault](http://code.google.com/p/android-assault/)

[APK Analyser](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/04/13/powerful-tool-to-analyse-your-apks-now-released-open-source/)

[Androguard](http://code.google.com/p/androguard/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at this fairly  simple shell script I wrote up to extract this information for Team City/continuous integration reports:

https://github.com/sveinungkb/android-apk-info

Let's you easily extract key metrics from an apk:

- method count
- class count
- apk size (bytes)
- .dex size (bytes)

Supports Team City's system messages so you can pick it up as a report. Should be easy to parse in Jenkins too.